# Spring JDBC session causes duplicate entry exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-session

In my Spring Boot project, there are REST and MVC controllers. Where the MVC part should have session. This part goes fine, but when you come from a MVC page with session and start using Swagger from the browser to the API I start to see these messages on the REST API endpoints:

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) VALUES (?, ?, ?)Duplicate entry '7a69e3fe-dd7f-4a1d-85bb-2dcd617225dd-SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUE' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '7a69e3fe-dd7f-4a1d-85bb-2dcd617225dd-SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUE' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:242)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.insertSessionAttributes(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:515)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.access$300(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:131)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository$2.doInTransactionWithoutResult(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:413)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.save(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:393)
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.save(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:131)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.saveSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:377)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '7a69e3fe-dd7f-4a1d-85bb-2dcd617225dd-SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUE' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:855)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

My security configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/index.html",
                        "/oauth2-redirect.html",
                        "/favicon-*.png",
                        "/swagger-*",
                        "/swagger.json"
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Need to use sql query that will ignore duplicate. Spring already have the correct one, you just need to enable it:

```
@Configuration
class DatabaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public MySqlJdbcIndexedSessionRepositoryCustomizer sessionRepositoryCustomizer() {
        return new MySqlJdbcIndexedSessionRepositoryCustomizer();
        // or PostgreSqlJdbcIndexedSessionRepositoryCustomizer
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 on that answer. More information in there https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1213#issuecomment-1675754642

Answer (score 2):

Appereantly there is a bug in delta session handling: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/1070

This should be fixed in version Spring Session `2.0.4.RELEASE`, I worked on version Spring Session `2.0.3.RELEASE` and have now downgraded to Spring Session `1.3.2.RELEASE` which resolved my issues (which is in spring boot `1.5.13.RELEASE`). 
Will try again when version `2.0.4.RELEASE` is out.

**UPDATE**: I tested the SNAPSHOT version, suggested [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1081)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

This is resolving my issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're affected by this on `2.0.2.RELEASE`? That shouldn't be the case, since [gh-1070](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/1070) is about regression introduced in `2.0.3.RELEASE`.

Comment: @VedranPavic I have tested it with SNAPSHOT, which works (I updated my answer too). So it seems the issue is related to what I am facing.

Comment: I think you are mixing Spring Session and Spring Boot releases - you said you downgraded to `1.5.13.RELEASE` however there is no such Spring Session release, so I assume that's Spring Boot release you're using. So the `2.0.2.RELEASE` part of your answer actually refers to Spring Boot as well, rather than Spring Session. And Spring Boot `2.0.2.RELEASE` actually pulls in Spring Session `2.0.3.RELEASE` via its dependency management.

Comment: @VedranPavic You are right. I made some assumptions on the spring session versions. I updated my answer to make it more clear